# Font Awesome Issue In PHP

Tags: php

I'm Very New To Php And Try To Create Frontend For Website In Php.

I Connect fontawesome.all.css File To Index.php But When I Run Website , **Icons Doesn't Show** ?

**Linked Link This :**

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('home/xit_load_files/css/fontawesome-all.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

**My Code Is** :

```
<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list"></i> Get a demo</a>
```

Here Screenshot of Web:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZcZV.png)

Comment: What is the resulting client-side value for the `href` attribute in your `<link>` element?  Is it what you expect?  In the browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, when the page makes a request for that CSS resource, what is the server's response?

Comment: My guess is you are missing a `/` at the start of the href : `/home/xit....` . But I'm not sure what the output is now

Answer (score 0):

You tell fontawesome.min.css but, you are included fontawesome-all.css
May be this wrong.

Try change your code to

`<link href="<?php echo base_url('home/xit_load_files/css/fontawesome.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">`